# I am trying to insert a image using Postman

Tags: 8

Good afternoon,

I am trying to insert a image in Drupal from Postman.

The request URL is `http://<urldrupal>/drupal/node?_format=hal_json`.

The JSON structure inserted in the body is the following.

```json
{
  "url": "http://<urldrupal>/drupal/rest/type/file/image",
  "type": "POST",
  "data": {
    "_links": {"type": {"href": "http://<urldrupal>/drupal/rest/type/file/image"}},
    "filename": [{"value": "test.jpg"}],
    "filemime": [{"value": "image / jpeg"}],
    "type": [{"target_id": "image"}],
    "data": [{"value": "BASE64_VERSION_OF_THE_IMAGE_HERE"}]
  }
}
```

I get the following error.

```json
{
    "message": "The type link relation must be specified."
}
```

I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is this an image being attached to a node? If so, the node must already exist.  See detailed examples in the [change record on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/3024331).

Comment: Yes. I intend to insert the image in a node. What do i need to add to my json structure? Is necessary insert any variable referring to the node in the body?

Comment: Read the detailed description at the link; it's all described there.